# Need inputs on how to convert below mule3 to mule4 code

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mule4

We are migrating mule3 project to mule4 using MMA; during migration we encountered below mule3 code.
Any inputs on how to convert it to mule4?

```
#[flowVars.appendix.get(flowVars.currentCode).put(payload[0], payload[1])]
```

appendix =

```
{
  "Codes": "p184",
  "Data": "Useful",
  "Value": "1",
  "Definition": "Space Research Program"
}
```

currentCode =

```
"p184"
```

payload =

```
[
  "999",
  "0"
]
```

Comment: What is the expected output? In addition to all the inputs always remember to indicate the expected output.

Comment: The code doesn't look to make sense. `flowVars.appendix.get(flowVars.currentCode)` seems to be trying to get the value for a key, but the argument is a value, not a key. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The following script needs to be placed within a set variable/transform message processor with the variable name `appendix` (Essentially overwriting the appendix variable)

```
do {
    var currentCode = vars.currentCode
    var appendix_CC = vars.appendix[currentCode] default {}
    var value = {
        (payload[0]): payload[1]
    }   
    ---
   vars.appendix update {
        case ."$(currentCode)"! -> if (isEmpty(appendix_CC))  value else (appendix_CC ++ value)
    }
}
```